Differentiation under integral signs as done in basic quantum mechanics
In various text books, lectures or lecture notes on basic quantum mechanics, I've seen cases differentiating under integral signs and I am wondering why it is allowed in those situations.
The typical situation which always stuns me is like this: Let $\psi(t,x)$ ($t\in\mathbb{R}$, $ \ x\in\mathbb{R}^n$) be a solution of the Schrödinger equation
$$i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=H\psi\phantom{aaa}(H\text{ the Hamiltonian})$$
which can be normalized, i.e.
$$0<\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\psi(t,x)|^2 dx< \infty$$
for all $t$. Differentiation under the integral sign is then used to show that the value of the integral is independent of $t$:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\psi(t,x)|^2 dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t,x)|^2 dx = \ ... \text{(additional computations)} ... \ = 0$$
Now I am not concerned with the "additional computations" but I do not see why plugging $\frac{d}{dt}$ under the integral sign is allowed in this situation. To justify such a manipulation, the only criterion I know is to show that there is an integrable function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \to [0,+\infty)$ and an estimate
$$\biggl|\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t,x)|^2\biggr| \leq g(x)\phantom{aaa}\forall t\in I, \ \forall x\in\mathbb{R}^n$$
where $I$ is an arbitrary finite intervall in $\mathbb{R}$. However, I cannot see why this criterion is satisfied here.
Can anyone give me an idea of why differentiating under the integral sign is allowed in this situation? Is the critetion I mentioned satisfied and I just cannot see why? Or is there another theorem which justifies this and of which I am simply not aware? Or do we need some additional restrictions on the function $\psi(t,x)$ which physicists may not explicitly state in their texts?
$$\phantom{111}$$
Edit: As an exemplary reference, David J. Griffith uses this calculation in his book "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics" (page 12 in my edition of the book). He also uses a similar calculation to show the the time derivative of the expectation of the position operator gives the expectation of the momentum.

If this helps, there is also a theorem that guarantees the move of a derivative under the integral when  $\int_\limits{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi(t,x)|^2 dx $ converges uniformly. You can find it in Petrovic, John Srdjan - Advanced Calculus _ Theory and Practice-2013, page 375.
